# Using find command to find folder ignoring case

Tags: linux, find

I would like to know if a particular folder is present or not. I used the following command

```
find /mnt/md0/ -maxdepth 1 -name 'dcn'||'DCN'
```

I want to know if folder name is DCN  or dcn .
 How would I do this ?

Comment: an easy one too:  `find /mnt/md0 -type d -maxdepth 1 -print | grep -i '/dcn$'`

Comment: @OlivierDulac that's a major complication of process when the binary offers the possibility already, though it can be usefull on UNIX system without GNU binary.

Comment: @Kiwy: don't mind me, I always propose "portable" alternative, as I almost don't have any GNU version at work (but instead I have very ancient "historical" ones, even "tar who uncompress keeping the leading '/'" ...). I'm very concerned about portability (even if it means a bit more verbose solution, hence I just put as a comment here...). [on the other hand, I don't gracefully handle "weird filenames", but I never encountered filenames with embedded "returns" so far (whereas I use old utilities everyday)]  [I know there was a Linux tag, but still, it's to give alternatives for other viewers]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're looking for the option `-iname`, which stands for "ignore case" on `GNU find` along with the option `-type d` for selecting only directories.

```
find /mnt/md0/ -type d -maxdepth 1 -iname dcn
```

For more a detail explanation on find switches you consult [explainshells.com's](http://explainshell.com/) explanation of [find](http://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=find%20/mnt/md0/%20-type%20d%20-maxdepth%201%20-iname%20dcn). (This will match any case: `dcn` , `DcN`, `DCn`)

#### Edit 1:

<strike>As state in comment by [Olivier Dulac](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/27616/olivier-dulac?tab=reputation) to use with non GNU find or old find version you could use :</strike>

```
find /mnt/md0 -type d -maxdepth 1 -print | grep -i '/dcn$'
```

see [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/113500/53092) to have a real compatibility with non GNU and old find version

Comment: @slm I do love that website, it's really nice when having to deal with lot of option on GNU binaries. thanks for the edit by the way.

Comment: Note that it matches dcn and DCN, but also Dcn, dCN... Note that beside GNU, like `-maxdepth`, `-iname` is also available in modern BSDs find and in busybox find.

Comment: The `find` implementations that don't have `-iname` are also likely not to have `-maxdepth`. Also note that you can't use `grep` on filenames as `grep` works on lines while filenames can be made of several line. See [my answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/113500/22565) for the standard/portable way.

Comment: @StephaneChazelas you're perfectly right, I do check on AIX and indeed no `maxdepth` argument

Answer (score 5):

You can use this:

```
find /mnt/md0/ -type d -maxdepth 1 \( -name 'dcn' -o -name 'DCN' \)
```

Answer (score 4):

Standardly:

```
find /mnt/md0/. ! -name . -prune -type d \( -name dcn -o -name DCN \)
```

Or for case insensitive match:

```
find /mnt/md0/. ! -name . -prune -type d -name '[dD][cC][nN]'
```

You don't necessarily need `find` though.

```
printf '%s\n' /mnt/md0/[dD][cC][nN]/
```